# Unit testing Boolean method based on other methods return types

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

New to unit testing and am looking for a way to unit test a Boolean method that is validated by two other methods results.

```
 protected boolean isUpdateNeeded(){ 
 return (method1() && method2()); 
}
```

the other methods look like this for this example.

```
protected boolean method1() { 
 return false; 
}

protected boolean method2() { 
 return true; 
}
```

But these two methods are/can be Overriden if need be. Idk if that really matter at this point

So my thinking behind the test is this. Find a way to pass true/false to method1 or method2 to meet the required possible outcomes.

```
@Test
 public void testCheckToSeeIfUpdateIsNeeded(){ 
   assertTrue('how to check here'); 
   asserFalse('how to check here');
   assertIsNull('was null passed?');  

 }
```

Comment: add parameters of type bool/Boolean?

Comment: i can't, the methods are used widely thru the app

Comment: Mock the two methods and have different scenarios where they return different combinations of true/false

Comment: Use a Mockito spy.  Stub the two methods in the spy, and test all the required scenarios of `isUpdateNeeded` directly on the spy.  (Disclaimer: I have, in the past, been associated with the Mockito project).

Comment: Identify the dependencies of your class and Mock them out. So that you can test your class in isolation, without access to resources and other classes. Only test the public interface of the class.

Comment: @Joakim can you or anyone show a little example of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If another class extends this and overrides method1 and method2, it's the responsibility of the person developing that class to test the change.

You could mock method1 and method2, but you're then coupling the structure of your class with your test cases, making it harder to make a change later.

Your responsibility here to test the *behavior* of your class. I see the method in question is called `isUpdateNeeded`. So let's test that. I'll fill out the class as I imagine it.

```
class Updater {
    Updater(String shouldUpdate, String reallyShouldUpdate) {...}
    boolean method1() { return shouldUpdate.equals("yes"); }
    boolean method2() { return reallyShouldUpdate.equals("yes!"); }
    boolean isUpdateNeeded() { ...}
}

class UpdaterTest {
    @Test
    void testUpdateIsNeededIfShouldUpdateAndReallyShouldUpdate() {
        String shouldUpdate = "yes";
        String reallyShouldUpdate = "yes!"
        assertTrue(new Updater(shouldUpdate, reallyShouldUpdate).isUpdateNeeded());
    }
    .... more test cases .....
}
```

Notice how this test asserts the behavior of the Updater given the inputs, not it's relationship to the existence of some other methods.

If you would like the test to demonstrate what happens if you override the methods, subclass Updater in the test and make the appropriate change.

Comment: Have you added a new constructor to the original class here?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm not sure what you're asking here. The original class hasn't been presented so I'm making up the structure to give an example of how to test.

Comment: Then I think this is a good answer, I also think using a Mock instead of Spy should also work. Right?

Comment: is the `assertTrue` missing a closing `)`?

Comment: @whisk it might be (I've added one just now). I typed that entirely into the SO editor, so there may be some minor syntax errors. I expect you correct them in your solution though.

Comment: Technically you are only covering 25% of the function's code paths here, and only 50% of the outcomes... :)   You should really add a test for false.

Comment: @Jocke You *could* use a mock or a spy, but I'm saying that neither is appropriate here because you'd be reaching in to test the internal structure of an object rather than its behavior.

Comment: @GonenI that's correct, but this question is about how to write good tests, not how to enumerate test cases. I've added a bit to show that the list of tests is not exhaustive.

Comment: IMHO the problem with using a spy here is not reaching into an internal structure as it uses the unit's API which is open for extension,  and it is not tying the code's structure to the test since method1/2 implementation changes could be just as likely to force changes to the test in this approach.  But since methods1 and 2 are within the unit anyway, if the different data paths can be tested without adding the complexity of another dependency, then they should be. This also increases code coverage within the unit, as any mocked out code is not tested.

Comment: @GonenI A counter argument to that: While this is part of the pubilc API, if it's not published outside this code base, it may be appropriate at some time to extract method1/2 into some other object and this test would make it more difficult. That said, neither argument is *right*, but they consider different tradeoffs which need to be understood in the context of OPs actual code.

Answer (score 2):

So, for example you have class:

```
public class BooleanBusiness {

  public boolean mainMethod(){
    return (firstBoolean() && secondBoolean());
  }

  public boolean firstBoolean(){
    return true;
  }

  public boolean secondBoolean() {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Then you can write tests like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class BooleanBusinessTest {

  @Test
  public void testFirstOption() {
    BooleanBusiness booleanBusiness = Mockito.spy(BooleanBusiness.class);
    when(booleanBusiness.firstBoolean()).thenReturn(true);
    when(booleanBusiness.secondBoolean()).thenReturn(true);
    assertTrue(booleanBusiness.mainMethod());
  }

  @Test
  public void testSecondOption() {
    BooleanBusiness booleanBusiness = Mockito.spy(BooleanBusiness.class);
    when(booleanBusiness.firstBoolean()).thenReturn(true);
    when(booleanBusiness.secondBoolean()).thenReturn(false);
    assertFalse(booleanBusiness.mainMethod());
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, lets just hope that firstBoolean() and secondBoolean() are public methods. I have a feeling they are not.

Comment: @Jocke It says in the question that they can be overridden so I think we can assume that they are not private at least

Comment: sorry I thought that I had added the access modifiers, I updated it.